# From oci response to a Python dictionary

Tags: python, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Looking to convert an oci response to a Python dict, so I can print out various fields. But I can't manage to get a Python dictionary object.

````
    import oci
    import json

    myresp = core_client.list_instances(compartment,display_name="myinstance").data
    # myresp is of type LIST
    # Convert the Python object response to a JSON string
    myjson = json.dumps(str(myresp))
    # myjson is of type STR
    # Convert JSON string to Python dict
    mypyth = json.loads(myjson)
    print(my_pyth['id'])
    # Script fails, mypyth is of type STR, not dict as expected```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by removing the outer [] brackets from the OCI response. You then have valid JSON, which you can convert to a Python dict.

```
import oci
import json

myresp = core_client.list_instances(compartment,display_name="myinstance").data
# myresp is of type LIST
# Strip out contents of the list
myresp_list = (myresp[0])

# Convert JSON string to Python dict
mypyth = json.loads(str(myjson_list))
print(my_pyth['id'])
# Script succeeds, mypyth is of type DIR as expected
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with ast:

```
  ast.literal_eval(myjson)
```

it should return the dict you are looking for.
Of course:

```
  import ast
```

Comment: ast reports that I have a string, not a dict as follows:
`TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: ast just confirms the Python types that I found originally. I still end up with a str type, not the dict type I was expecting.

Comment: Ok, if that's so i have to ask to paste a little example of the data you dealing with at each step: myresp, myjson, etc.